# Perl - Convert datetime stamp to datetime object

Tags: perl, datetime

How can I convert a DateTime stamp to a DateTime object?

DateTime string: `2015-05-25T03:47:44`

Is there a way to instantiate a DateTime object with this timestamp? If not, what's the best way to create a DateTime object with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [`DateTime::Format::ISO8601`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Format::ISO8601):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use DateTime::Format::ISO8601;

my $str = '2015-05-25T03:47:44';

my $dt = DateTime::Format::ISO8601->parse_datetime( $str );

print "$dt\n";
```

Comment: Note: Since the format doesn't include any time zone information, you need to follow up with `$dt->set_time_zone(...)` if you're going to do any dt arithmetic.